# Installing “atom-typescript@8.5.0” into GitHub's Atom Editor failed

Tags: atom-editor

I am trying to install the [atom-typescript](https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript) package for GitHub's Atom Editor. When I press the install button it displays following error message.

```
Installing "atom-typescript@8.5.0" failed.

  gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
  gyp info using node-gyp@2.0.2
  gyp info using node@0.10.40 | win32 | ia32
  gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/atom-shell/v0.34.5/node-v0.34.5.tar.gz
  gyp http 200 https://atom.io/download/atom-shell/v0.34.5/node-v0.34.5.tar.gz
  gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/atom-shell/v0.34.5/SHASUM256.txt
  gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/atom-shell/v0.34.5/node.lib
  gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/atom-shell/v0.34.5/x64/node.lib
  gyp http 200 https://atom.io/download/atom-shell/v0.34.5/x64/node.lib
  gyp http 200 https://atom.io/download/atom-shell/v0.34.5/node.lib
  gyp warn install got an error, rolling back install

Compiler tools not found

Packages that depend on modules that contain C/C++ code will fail to install.

Read here for instructions on installing Python and Visual Studio
```

Can't figure out what's the problem.

Has anybody encountered the same issue?

[image: Image displaying the error]

Comment: Is this a brand new install of `atom-typescript`, which version of Atom are you using and what other packages, if any, do you have installed?  I've just tried it out and successfully installed it in `Atom 1.7.0-beta4` which is the latest Beta version.

Answer (score 1):

you can install it manually instead

CD to `~/.atom/packages`
clone the project from github,

```
git clone https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript
```

cd to

```
   atom-typescript
```

and run

```
npm install
```

restart atom.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install from the command line by closing all instances of Atom then issuing the following command:

```
apm install atom-typescript
```

If this is not a fresh install then you will want to uninstall the previous package first:

```
apm uninstall atom-typescript
```

If you get the same error message you can check to see if the native tools are actually installed from Atom / apm's perspective:

```
apm install --check
```

If the latter command fails then you can update your question with any details.